# Pycharm starting a new Jupyter notebook everytime a cell is set to run

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

My current setup is the following:

- Windows 8.1
- Anaconda 64 bits (Python 3.5)
- PyCharm Community Edition

I've configured PyCharm to use Anaconda's Python and everything is running smoothly.

But when I tried to follow this [Jupyter tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/tutorial-using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html) (Jupyter comes with Anaconda BTW), I found that PyCharm behaves quite differently from what the docs describe.

Every time I run a cell (either with the "play" button or ctrl+enter) it starts a new Jupyter Notebook, adds a new input cell and does not show outputs.

Has anyone experienced this problem recently? Am I missing something?

Comment: Which version of PyCharm are you using? (You can go to `Help -> About` to find out.)  Is it `2016.1`?

Answer (score 0):

A little late: I ran into the same issue, on my setup it was fixed by the upgrade to PyCharm CE 2016.3.1. The [changelog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/12/pycharm-2016-3-1-released/) mentions *IPython and Jupyter Notebook fixes* - so maybe it has been one of those.

Setup:

- OS X 10.11.6
- Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)
- PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.1

Comment: I'm seeing this on 2016.3.2